# Visual Studio 2019 no muestra imágenes. WPF XAML C#

Tags: c#, imagen, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

La cosa es que no sé dónde está el fallo:

1. Abro Visual Studio 2019
2. Creo un proyecto WPF nuevo
3. Copio una imagen cualquiera a la carpeta del proyecto (o a una subcarpeta)
4. En el código XAML, dentro del Grid agrego una etiqueta Image

```
        <Grid>
                <Image Source="Imagen.jpg"/>
        </Grid>>
```

5. En la vista diseño aparece mi imagen sin problema
6. Inicio la depuración y mi imagen NO ESTÁ!!!!!

He abierto varios proyectos, he probado con Grid y con StackPanel, he probado con .png y con .jpg y el comportamiento sigue siendo el mismo; cuando pico código no me da errores de ningún tipo y de hecho se ven mis cambios en la ventana diseño, pero a la hora de iniciar la depuración no hay ni rastro de las imágenes.  Estaría muy agradecido si alguien sabe qué puede estar fallando o qué puedo estar haciendo mal. Gracias por leerme y gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Prueba seteando la imagen a través del panel de la derecha y no escribiendo el nombre del archivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola trata de poner la imagen como Resource

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo copié el archivo en la carpeta del proyecto. La solución fué agregarlo al proyecto dentro de Visual Studio en el Explorador de Soluciones; una vez hecho esto la imagen se puso como Resouce.y todo funcionó correctamente. No obstante estuve viendo un tutorial donde no agregaron la imagen al Explorador de Soluciones y además usaron una ruta absoluta para la imagen que se encontraba en otra carpeta que nada tenía que ver.  De todos modos tu respuesta fue genial, eres un crack!! muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso primero cambio la propiedad como propuso Jorge Luis y no funcionó, luego en la opción de "Compilar" solo le das limpiar solucion o limpiar tu app.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me levantó la imagen.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).